# Is there a Linux equivalent of LightIngest.exe?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a Linux equivalent of LightIngest.exe? The [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/lightingest) of the utility does not mention that, search brings no luck either. In case it is not available, what is the preferred way to post ingestion items through CLI in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now LightIngest is [published as a dotnet tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.LightIngest/)

Alternatively you can download a standalone application OS specific of [LightIngest](https://github.com/Azure/Kusto-Lightingest/releases), for Linux, Osx and windows

For the second option one doesn't need to have dotnet at all (like in @real_goda answer), although this solution would work for the other tools that are still not published as standalone, i.e Kusto.CLI

Answer (score 4):

There is a .NET Core Kusto.Tools package - it is currently built for Core 2.1 and we will be working on updating it in the coming weeks.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools.NETCore/

Comment: Do you mean I can build LightIngest for Core, or I need to write some custom code using this package?

Comment: Kusto.Tools is a collection of built binaries, LihjtIngest is part of it.
This is a "copy-deployable" package - just extract its contents and use.

Comment: @greatvovan - please accept my answer instead as things have changed :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Vladik's answer I was able to download the package and use the included `LightIngest.dll` to execute an ingest through my Mac. Here are the steps:

1. Use nuget to download the `Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools.NETCore` package installed:

```
nuget install Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools.NETCore  -Source nuget.org -OutputDirectory SPECIFY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
```

2. Navigate to the directory, and go to the `tools` subfolder. There you should find `LightIngest.dll`
3. Assuming you have `dotnet` installed (CLI) and SDK (v2.1) you should be able to execute an ingestion:

```
dotnet ./LightIngest.dll ...
```

Replace the `...` with the Windows equivalent command that Azure Data Explorer Ingestion wizard suggested, and it should start ingesting!